# Aligning items vertically in Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

Helo everyone!
Can not figure out how to align vertically items in Bootstrap 5 on a specific example. The row is separated into two columns ( col-md-6 ) and I want to position two items in only the first column one in the middle of the flexbox and the other in the end. I can't separate the two items, the only thing that works is to move them together. Any thoughts?

```
<div class="row min-vh-100" id="about">
  <div class="col-md-6 bg-red d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2>ABOUT</h2>
    </div> 

      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
      <div class="text-center">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">about me /</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">projects /</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero expedita 
    ea assumenda aperiam? Nam atque dolorum aut quo, 
    magni voluptatum aspernatur consequatur doloremque excepturi, reprehenderit,
    vitae eius similique doloribus? Quae?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `justify-content-between` to spread the elements across the start, middle and end section of your column. To push the heading in the middle and the menu to the bottom, just add an empty `<div>` as first element in your column.

You can find pretty good pictured tutorial on flex-items [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox).

```
<div class="row min-vh-100" id="about">
  <div class="col-md-6 bg-red d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
    <div class="w-100"> <!-- just an empty box with 100% width --></div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <h2>ABOUT</h2>
    </div> 

      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
      <div class="text-center">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">about me /</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">projects /</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
     
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero expedita 
    ea assumenda aperiam? Nam atque dolorum aut quo, 
    magni voluptatum aspernatur consequatur doloremque excepturi, reprehenderit,
    vitae eius similique doloribus? Quae?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot m8, this was exactly what I needed :)